# How to set a specific length of 10 or 17 for a string in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc, validation

I need to set string field with a specific length. Below is the code I use,

```cs
    [Required]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength =10, ErrorMessage = "ID must be 10 digits long.")]
    public string ID{ get; set; }
```

Here length must be 10 digits. But I want to set the length of ID to **10** or **17** digits long, not between. That is my valid ID must be of length 10 or 17. Need help about this...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a RegularExpression attribute for that.

```
[RegularExpression("(.{17}|.{10})", ErrorMessage = "Length must be 10 or 17.")]
```